# does jxcore package for node.js lauch the app in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, jxcore

i have created windows application using jxcore and mean stack. The executable file works fine and pages are also getting displayed properly. The problem is everytime i have to go to browser and open the localhost:2000 to launch the app. jxcore package runs only the node server but not the browser. Is this the nature of jxcore or i have missed something while creating jxcore executable.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is the nature of jxcore, in the same way as node.js. one of the simplest way is using node-open: https://www.npmjs.com/package/open.

you can also try project previously known as "node-webkit" (http://nwjs.io/), that allows creating browser together with node code.